# replicate numpy style array initialisation in c++

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, initialization

I'm trying to replicate basic NumPy functionalities in C++ (for practice).

I'm stuck replicating the following initialization:
here's how it looks in python/NumPy:

```
x = np.array([[1], [2]])
```

which evaluates to:

```
array([[1],
       [2]])
```

In my C++ code, I decided to use `std::vector`. I currently have two functions to initialize arrays (I want to use overloading so that I can always use the same function name when initializing an array).

function1 declaration for 1D arrays:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> init(std::vector<int> vec);
```

I can use this like so:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec1d = init({0, 1, 2});
```

function2 declaration for 2D arrays:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> init(std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec);
```

I can use this like so:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec2d = init({{0, 1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}});
```

However, I'm unable to implement the NumPy-like initialization shown at the top of my question.
If I try to run the following line:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec2d = init({{0}, {1}});
```

I get the following error:

```
error: call to 'init' is ambiguous
```

I thought that the 2D version of the function would be called.

What do I have to change (or what other overloaded functions do I have to add) in order for this type of initialization to work?

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec1d{{0, 1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}};` for the 2D version; no function necessary. I'm not sure I understand how 1D version is supposed to turn a 1D vector into 2D vector. What's the expected result of `init({0, 1, 2})`?

Comment: In python `[[1], [2]]` is parsed as a list of lists (of integers)  `np.array` deduces it needs to make a (2,1) shaped array with `int` dtype.  It uses `shape` and `strides` to define  the multidimensionality.  The values are actually stored in a flat `c` array.

Comment: As an aside, as far as I understand, a `numpy.ndarray` is not really equivalent to `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.  The python equivalent would be a list of lists

Comment: You will want to write a custom class to mimic `numpy.ndarray` instead of using a vector of vectors. How that is done is way beyond the scope of a question.

Comment: I already have a class that mimics numpy.ndarray, I'm only struggling with the data input/initialisation so that it is like in numpy (internally I store everything as a `double**`). I could simply pass strings that look like the NumPy style, e.g. `"[[1], [2]]"` and then write custom parsing code, but I hoped that that there is already some functionality that I can use

Comment: Short answer: c++ and python are different languages with different constructs. You cant just replicate every aspect one-to-one. If you want to see how a good numerics library can look like in c++, check out Eigen or Armadillo.